# Как изменить режим масштабирования окна в WPF

Tags: wpf

Делаю кнопки управления окном на панели кастомные и столкнулся с проблемой, что окно масштабируется буквально на весь экран, абсолютно на весь. Для масштабирования использую

WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

Получаемый результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Желаемый результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Только чтобы была кастомная панель сверху

Comment: Эм... Я что-то не понимаю, или это два совершенно одинаковых скрина?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, изменил

Comment: Пример дайте, который так делает, ибо если взять пустой WPF проект, задать ему `WindowState="Maximized"`, то он у вас вообще не затронет каким либо образом панель Windows снизу, а у вас вдруг она пропадает, чего быть не может.

Comment: Она не пропадает, он просто поверх него лепит почему-то. Задано WindowStyle="None" и WindowState="Maximized". Если в пустом проекте так задать то будет то же самое.

Comment: Как трудно сразу всю информацию дать, да?) С `None` да, такое будет, решение можете посмотреть например [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20941443/6808809).

Comment: спасибо большое!